# Apply CSS to a particualar menu item asp.net menu

Tags: css, asp.net, menu

I have an asp.net horizonatal menu with 4 Menu Items. The 2nd one has a submenu.
All of them are center aligned but due to the submenu, the text of the 2nd element appears to be shifted to left. I want apply css to this particular menu item.

```
                                    <Items>
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="" Value="" NavigateUrl=""></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="" Value="" NavigateUrl=""> // want to apply CSS to this particular Item in such a way that it shouldn't break if the order of the items is changed.
                                        <asp:MenuItem Text="" Value="" NavigateUrl="></asp:MenuItem>
                                    </asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="" Value="" NavigateUrl=""></asp:MenuItem>

                                </Items>
```

Answer (score 2):

Top level items have the class "static" applied to them, all item inside them have the class "dynamic" (there are other classes as well but check the markup). You can't apply particular class to an item (you can but it's a huge pain) but you can do a CSS trick to get the result you're searching for:

- Set a "Tooltip" to the item in particular - it will be rendered as a "title" attribute in the HTML
- In your CSS file add a selector by attribute, i.e. ".navigation a[title='{{THE_TOOLTIP_VALUE}}'] { color: red; }"

**NOTE:** You can fool around with the styles and classes via the Menu properties or the additional elements in the Menu control. For full reference, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.aspx

**Personal opinion:** By default the asp:Menu has predefined CSS classes, inline styles and you get some out of the box JavaScript applied (via the ScriptResource.axd handler). At some point you'll need to remove those or alternate them ... and you'll start pulling your hair :) It takes couple of hours to write your own HTML menu generator - don't spend days trying to figure out how to modify the Menu control because it's pointless.

Comment: can't get it with tooltip. just can't find the control.

Comment: For the same of the test, just add the 'Tooltip="xyz" in the 'MenuItem' and '*[title="xyz"]{color:red;}' in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Add `CssClass="SomeMenuClass"` in that corresponding `asp:Menu` and and give style details like

```
.SomeMenuClass a
{/*menu items with submenu*/
    color:black;
}
.SomeMenuClass a:only-child
{/*menu items without submenu*/
    color:Green;
}
```

Comment: MenuItem does not support CssClass property.